# What is the shutdown command in MFC?

Tags: mfc

I want to shutdown the PC when I click on a button. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the [ExitWindowsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868%28VS.85%29.aspx) API function with the `EWX_SHUTDOWN` flag.

You can find a sample here: [How to Shut Down the System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376871%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a System() call.